# Configuring Karma coverage with Jasmine adapter

Tags: testing, jasmine, code-coverage, karma-runner

The [Karma coverage documentation](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/coverage.html) mentions a bad configuration example:

> In this example also JASMINE and JASMINE_ADAPTER get included but they shouldn't as these file are only for the test setup used and not for your program.

However, on the [files documentation page](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.8/config/files.html), they mention that you should include JASMINE and JASMINE_FRAMEWORK in the files array.

I would like to use Karma with Jasmine. And I would like to try out the code coverage.

So how do I set this up?

Comment: "Heads Up! You're viewing the docs for v0.8, an old version of Karma. v0.12 is the newest". Are you sure you want to use karma v0.8?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That's what happens when people set their websites up to redirect to a version number.